# Recursive select

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm tried to create a SQL statement using `WITH` but I can't get it right.

I got the following tables;

Groups (Id, Name)

```
1, 'My app'
2, 'Local admins'
3, 'Global admins'
```

Users (1, Name)

```
1, 'Arne'
```

GroupOwners (GroupId, OwnerType, OwnerId)

```
1, 'Group', 2
```

GroupMembers (GroupId, MemberType, MemberId)

```
2, 'Group', 3
3, 'User', 1
```

I'm trying to find all groups that `Arne` is a owner of. In this case it's `My App`. But the thing is that `Local Admins` is set as the owner. And `Global admins` is a member of `Local admins`. And `Arne` is finally a member of `Global admins`.

[image]

*never mind the diamonds, they are incorrect*

The nesting varies from group to group. (Some have the user directly in GroupOwners while others may have one group with users as members)

Is it possible to solve with one mother of SQL statement? Additional constraint: `Groups`/`Users` are used elsewhere in the system.

Comment: You're going to need to give us a better ERD of your database example. You seem to be mixing database entities with specific rows (Arne and MyApp) in your diagram, confusing the matter.

Comment: It's not ERD, but illustrating the relationship between the different objects. Use it together with the listed tables and their values. Or as: `Group -> GroupOwners -> GroupMembers -> User`. It could have been  `Group -> GroupOwners -> GroupMembers -> GroupMembers -> User` or `Group -> GroupOwners -> User`. Always a step through the GroupOwner and 0..* steps through groupMembers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is recursive cte that will first find groups `Arno` is a member of and then match all the groups that directly or indirectly contain those groups. Results are finally joined to GroupOwners to limit results. Note: if `Arno` might be owner of a group, but not a member of it, this query will need UNION to append these groups also.

```
declare @UserID int = 1

; with allTheGroups as (
  select gm.GroupID
    from GroupMembers gm
   where gm.MemberType = 'User'
     and gm.MemberID = @UserID
  union all
  select gm.GroupID
    from GroupMembers gm
   inner join allTheGroups
      on gm.MemberID = allTheGroups.GroupID
   where gm.MemberType = 'Group'
)
select Groups.*
  from Groups
 inner join GroupOwners gow
    on Groups.ID = gow.GroupID
   and gow.OwnerType = 'Group'
 inner join allTheGroups a
    on gow.OwnerID = a.GroupID
```

[Sql Fiddle with example is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6f1d/2).

Example union to retrieve users who directly own a group added. Needs to be appended to query above (and select list tweaked, of course).

```
union
select gow.OwnerID, Users.Name
  from GroupOwners gow
 inner join Users
    on gow.OwnerID = Users.ID
   and gow.OwnerType = 'User'
 where gow.OwnerID = @UserID
```

Comment: Arne is a member of Global Admins (last group members row) and not a direct owner.

Comment: I have to first lookup all owners of each group (single select). And then traverse all owners which are groups until I find 'arne` as a member down the chain.

Comment: @jgauffin I'm trying different approach, starting with Arne's memberships to avoid the need to flatten entire structure. Hopefully I'll find the way.

Comment: @jgauffin Please take a look at my amended answer.

Comment: great job, thanks. Now I just have to try to understand it =)

Comment: @jgauffin You are welcome :-). Upper part of cte retrieves groups `Arno` is a member of; lower part finds all the groups which are members of previously selected groups by joining them on `gm.MemberID = allTheGroups.GroupID`. Process continues until no additional group is found.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, your tables are modeled incorrectly. You need to have two tables only. Groups and Admins(or Users, depending on your scenario).

Then you store stuff like "Local" or "Global" or the name (Arne) in the Admin/User table. Then it's a trivial select or join between only two tables. No nesting/recursion necessary.

Let me know if you need me to draw you an ERD or something to explain.

Comment: Not possible. `Groups` and `Users` are used for other things in the system too. they can not be joined.

Comment: Well I can sit and try to lecture you about database design here till I'm blue in the face, but that won't change the fact that you have the additional constraint of not being allowed to change the database model. I will edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Well. It's a sync from Active Directory and represents the AD structure.